# GET request from Cloudinary Failed. Error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: reactjs, cors, vite, cloudinary

I'm making a request to cloudinary API from a React & Vite App. I Keep getting these two errors:

Acess to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/sombra/image/list' from origin 'https://7aac-2806-2a0-1400-85b6-f0cb-e8b0-4880-f0ed.ngrok-free.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

and

ImageGallery.jsx?t=1688258885347:26     GET https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/sombra/image/list net::ERR_FAILED 404 (Not Found)   (i checked many times and the cloud name is correct)

This is the component:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const ImageGallery = () => {
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchImages = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(
          'https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/sombra/image/list'
        );

        setImages(response.data.resources);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching images:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchImages();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Image Gallery</h1>
      <div>
        {images.map((image) => (
          <img
            key={image.public_id}
            src={image.secure_url}
            alt={image.public_id}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default ImageGallery;
```

I tried to make a tunnel since apparently this error is very common and it can be caused by my PC. Also tried to update CORS rules in my vite.config.js file but doesnt seem to work either. This is the code that I'm pasting

```
 server: {
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/sombra/image/list",
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ""),
      },
    },
  },
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide your `API_KEY`, `API_SECRET`, and your `cloud_name` which you can find on the dashboard, and replace it with the values in the URL below

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const response = await axios.get("https://<API_KEY>:<API_SECRET>@api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/<cloud_name>/resources")
```

Here is a link to the documentation: [Get resources from cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/search_api)

Comment: The link you shared is to the Search API rather than the 'Get Resources' method of the Admin API. Also, Search/Admin API cannot be called via a cross-origin request.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the API endpoint you are making a request to (`https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/sombra/image/list`) doesn't match any Cloudinary API endpoint.

I assume you were attempting to call the [Get Resources](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/admin_api#get_resources) method of the [Admin API](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/admin_api) to get a list of assets with "resource_type" `image` and "type" `list`. If so, the request URL is missing the `resources` after your cloud name. In other words, it should be:

```
https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/sombra/resources/image/list
```

Admin API methods are not supported to be called as part of Cross-Origin requests (e.g. through AJAX/XHR etc) and therefore, the CORS error you are seeing is expected and the correct response.

The Admin API use Basic Authentication with your cloud's `API Key` and `API Secret`. The `API Secret` should not be used/exposed on the client side and only be used on the server side.

If you want to use any of the methods that are part of the Admin API, you should make the requests from your backend server. You can do so by either directly calling the API endpoint with any HTTP library or you could use one of Cloudinary's [Backend SDKs](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/cloudinary_sdks#backend) to perform the call. The SDKs provide wrappers for Cloudinary's API, including Admin, and you can just call the dedicated methods of the API you want to invoke and pass the parameters it requires, without needing to construct the request yourself.